# Persistent Windows in PyGTK

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, x11

Is there a way to force a gtk.Window object to ignore the Window Manager's show/hide commands, such as "iconify" and "show desktop?"

I'm trying to create a persistent window, stuck to the desktop, that will not disappear with all other windows when the desktop is exposed.

**EDIT:** I guess what I'm wondering specifically is whether or not it's possible to reproduce the behavior found in applications such as docks, desktop widgets, system trays, etc. using PyGTK?

Comment: Why would you do this?  It seems like very bad practice to ignore a user request to hide all the windows.

Comment: In the hopes of building something akin to a desktop widget, where the "show desktop" function of a window manager could provide easy access thereto. Maybe it's a mistake to try to use a Window object for this; I'm open to other suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got it backwards; it's not the window manager telling the window to minimize, by sending it a command. The window manager **owns** the window, if it wants to stop mapping a window, it will just do it, without asking the window for permission.

So I would think that the answer is "no".

Comment: Then I guess my question is, more generally, what would be a best-practice approach to creating a desktop widget using PyGTK?

Comment: Check if there's support for "sticky" windows, that might be the proper hint to the manager not to minimize the window. It usually also makes the window appear in the same location an all (virtual) desktops, which might be good.

Comment: I know about the "sticky" property, and it works just as it should, but this is not honored by any of the WMs I've tested in the way I intend.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the [`GdkWindowTypeHint`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gdk/unstable/gdk-Windows.html#GdkWindowTypeHint) on the `GtkWindow`:

```
gtk_window_set_type_hint(the_window, GDK_WINDOW_TYPE_HINT_UTILITY);
```

There's also various methods for not having your window listed in pagers or taskbars and have it show up on all desktop. Keep in mind that all this behavior depends on support from the window manager. Unless you use something really old, this should not pose a problem though.

Comment: And if you use something really old, it'll probably be a lot easier :)

Answer (score 1):

From the [list of window type hints](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Windows.html#GdkWindowTypeHint), only two are still shown when you click the show desktop button:

- gtk.gdk.WINDOW_TYPE_HINT_DESKTOP
- gtk.gdk.WINDOW_TYPE_HINT_DOCK

Both of these cause your window to lose decorations (i.e. no borders or titlebar) so moving/resizing is up to your app.  DESKTOP causes the window to be always behind other windows.  DOCK causes it to be always in front.

Choosing SPLASHSCREEN give you an undecorated window that still hides when you click show desktop.

If you want a borderless, immobile window that still shows when the user clicks "show desktop" use:

```
window.set_type_hint(gtk.gdk.WINDOW_TYPE_HINT_DOCK)
```

before you call window.show().  Once the window has been displayed, you can't change its type.

Answer (score 0):

Not having received a "this is how to do this" answer and having done a bit more research I can say that -- as far as I know -- there is no easy way to achieve this sort of functionality with PyGTK. The best options are to set window manager hints and leave it up to the WM to do what you want (hopefully).

Answer (score 0):

I think `gtk_window_set_type_hint(window, GDK_WINDOW_TYPE_HINT_SPLASHSCREEN)` is what you want. It is also `GDK_WINDOW_TYPE_HINT_DOCK`, but then the window stay on top of all, and you can't send it back.